# XQL Check all sub nodes for value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Ticket>
<PlannedTraffic>
    <Action>
        <Value>Allow</Value>
    </Action>
    <Destination>
        <Value>*</Value>
    </Destination>
    <ServiceApplication>
        <Value>tcp/80</Value>
    </ServiceApplication>
    <Source>
        <Value>10.130.5.5</Value>
    </Source>
    <ABF_flow_comment>Subscribe value</ABF_flow_comment>
</PlannedTraffic>
<PlannedTraffic>
    <Action>
        <Value>Allow</Value>
    </Action>
    <Destination>
        <Value>*</Value>
    </Destination>
    <ServiceApplication>
        <Value>tcp/22</Value>
    </ServiceApplication>
    <ServiceApplication>
        <Value>tcp/21</Value>
    </ServiceApplication>
    <Source>
        <Value>10.130.5.17</Value>
    </Source>
    <ABF_flow_comment>Comment with the word subscribe</ABF_flow_comment>
</PlannedTraffic>
</Ticket>
```

Using XQL I need to check if all the  contains the word "Subscribe". If all of them contains the word subscribe then return true or all of the nodes. If 1 or more of them does NOT contain the word subscribe I need it to return false or nothing.
Which XQL could be used for that?

I've tried the following but it only returns the nodes with the values "Subscribe" and I can't detect if just 1 node does not contain it. I guess I need something with count() and then compare to the amount of  nodes but I'm not sure how to make that XQL query

```
Ticket/PlannedTraffic[ABF_flow_comment =~ '/[sS]ubscribe/']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not

```
not(Ticket/PlannedTraffic[not(contains(ABF_flow_comment, 'ubscribe'))])
```

it returns `true` only if there is no `PlannedTraffic` not having such `ABF_flow_comment`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I had to remove the surround not() and it worked perfectly! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to help! If the answer solved your problem, you could accept it by pressing green mark at the left

Answer (score 0):

Not being completely familiar with the syntax, I can tell you how I would accomplish it.  I'd create an XPath for all nodes, regardless of subscribe status with:

Ticket/PlannedTraffic

I would then compare the count of your XPath's returned items versus the total items returned with the XPath above.  If they are the same, then all are subscribed.  In Java with Selenium I would use:

```
int totNodes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//Ticket/PlannedTraffic").size();
int subNodes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//Ticket/PlannedTraffic[contains(@ABF_flow_comment,"ubscribed")]").size();
Boolean isAllSubscribed = (totNodes == subNodes);
```

Hope that helps at least give you a direction to go.